# Give an example of the $a,b,c$ which satisfies conditions in the generating set

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How to derive the specific case of the generating element of a group given its generating set. For example, when 
$$G=\langle a,b,c|a^3=b^3=c^2=1,ab=ba,ca=a^2c,cb=b^2c\rangle$$
we can let $G\subset S_3\times S_3$, and let
$$a=((123),1),b=(1,(123)),c=((12),(12))$$
to get the desired result. However, when $3$ is replaced by general $p$, where $p$ is an odd prime,say,
$$G=\langle a,b,c|a^p=b^p=c^2=1,ab=ba,aca=c,bcb=c\rangle$$
 I cannot specifically give the example of $a,b$ and $c$, which satisfies "$a^p=b^p=c^2=1,ab=ba,aca=c,bcb=c$"  Is there any quick way to do so?

Comment: I don't think your phrase «How to derive the specific case of the generating element of a group given its generating set.» makes at all clear what you are trying to ask!

Comment: What does "specific case of the generating element of a group" mean? Do you mean finding elements in a group that correspond to the letters used in a given group presentation?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, you are right. But I cannot get a better intepretion of my question, can you give me a clearer expression of the question? Thank you !

Comment: @anon Yes, I want to find some $a,b,c$ to satisfies $ab=ba,aca=c..$ etc.

Comment: Dear Golbez, I cannot guess what you want to know! My mind-reading machine is not working today :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to find an embedding of your group $G \hookrightarrow S_p \times S_p$, the product of symmetric groups.  Let
$$
a = ((1\;2\; \cdots \; p), 1),
$$
$$
b = (1, (1\;2\; \cdots \; p)),
$$
$$
\text{and} \quad c = (r, r),
$$
where $r = (1, p-1)(2, p-2)\cdots$ is the reflection that fixes $p$.  (This actually embeds $G$ in $D_p \times D_p$, the product of dihedral groups.)

Comment: Your mind-reading machine is working well :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct generalization is
$$G=\langle a,b,c \mid a^p=b^p=c^2=1,ab=ba,cac=a^{-1},cbc=b^{-1}\rangle$$
where $p$ is any prime.

Take a vector space $V$ of dimension $2$ over $\Bbb{Z}_{p}$, *written multiplicatively*, with basis $a, b$. (In other words, $V$ is an elementary abelian group of order $p^{2}$ generated by $a, b$.) Let $c$ be the automorphism of $V$ given by inversion.

Now build $G$ as the semidirect product $V \langle c \rangle$.

Comment: Actually, your generalization is the same as mine. $cac=a^{-1} \leftrightarrow acac=1 \leftrightarrow aca = c^{-1}=c$. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: As $p$ is prime, it is not necessary to make the $2$ into a $-1$. You still get a semi-direct product. I presume the groups will be non-isomorphic, although I haven't checked.

Comment: @Golbez, you are quite right. I rewrote the relations in a way that displays explicitly  the action of $c$ on $\langle a, b \rangle$.

Comment: @user1729, well, for $p = 3$ you cannot tell whether you have a $2$ or a $-1$. However, OP in his presentation for a general $p$ makes it clear he reads it as a $-1$.